# Autocomplete depois de colar texto Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, autocompletar, sharepoint

Olá,

Estou com o seguinte problema no Sharepoint na seguinte input:

```
<input id="listNCM" class="ms-long ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Está input busca produtos através de números, o cara começa a digitar o número e o autocomplete mostra as sugestões, se o cara clicar na sugestão tudo certo, o Sharepoint salva. Se o cara colar o número completo do produto e não clicar na sugestão ele não salva.

Alguma dica de como o autocomplete pode buscar sozinho o código "colado"?

Comment: Como o Sharepoint sabe que que uma sugestão foi clicada? Tem algum exemplo de código?

Comment: @sam funciona igual a sugestão de pesquisa do google, seria tipo um .push, quando você cola o número do produto completo ele só mostra o produto, se fosse possível puxar esse produto pra input.

Comment: mas de onde vem os dados? de uma lista do sharepoint?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, exite uma lista com todos os produtos.

Comment: então você pode fazer com que o `input` pegue de uma lista, precisa usar as classes `javascript` de serviço do `sharepoint`

Comment: Vc pode disparar um click na sugestão que combina com o que foi colado: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpd2oxmz/2/